# Are composite primary keys in JPA with Quarkus possible?

Tags: java, jpa, kotlin, quarkus

**How to JPA-declare a composite key with Quarkus?**

Trying to use multiple `@Id` annotations in an `@Entity` class with Quarkus, results in the error:

```
Currently the @Id annotation can only be placed on a single field or method. Offending class is abc.model.Property
    at io.quarkus.spring.data.deployment.generate.StockMethodsAdder.getIdAnnotationTargetRec(StockMethodsAdder.java:940)
```

But first, after declaring

```
interface PropertyRepository : CrudRepository<Property, Pair<String, abc.model.Entity>>
```

Without the declaration above, there are no complaints, but no possibility to actively manage instances of `Property`.

**How to circumvent this error?**

I'm dealing with two JPA Entities:
1. the first one named `Entity` (don't mistake for the annotation)
2. the second one named `Property`

An `Entity` can have 0..n instances of `Property`. The code is as follows:

```
@Entity
data class Entity (
        @Id
        @Column(name = "entity_id", updatable = false)
        var entityId: String? = null,

        @Column(nullable = true)
        var type: String? = null
) {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity")
    var properties: List<Property>? = null
}
```

```
@Entity
data class Property (
        @Id
        @Column(name = "type")
        var type: String? = null,

        @Id
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id")
        private var entity: abc.model.Entity? = null
) : Serializable
```

---

Declaring the composite primary key as an `@EmbeddedId` as follows, does not solve the problem, as Quarkus currently doesn't allow other annotations than `@Id` in this case:

```
@Entity
data class Entity (
        @Id
        @Column(name = "entity_id", updatable = false)
        var entityId: String? = null,

        @Column(nullable = true)
        var type: String? = null
) {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "propertyId.entityId")
    var properties: List<Property>? = null
}

interface PropertyRepository : CrudRepository<Property, PropertyId>

@Embeddable
data class PropertyId (
        var type: String? = null,

        @Column(name = "entity_id")
        private var entityId: String? = null
) : Serializable

@Entity
data class Property (
        @EmbeddedId
        var propertyId: PropertyId? = null,

        @Column(name = "constant_value")
        var constantValue: String? = null
)
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Currently only Entities with the @Id annotation are supported. Offending class is abc.model.Property
    at io.quarkus.spring.data.deployment.generate.StockMethodsAdder.getIdAnnotationTargetRec(StockMethodsAdder.java:932)
```

Comment: As the error says you can't have Id annotation twice, if Property has a composite key then you must create a new class for it

Comment: @lucsbelt But the new class still would have the Id annotation twice. So, how that could be a solution?

Comment: You have two alternatives: use an Embeddable (i prefer this one) or use the IdClass annotation check out this examples https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id#Composite_Primary_Key

Comment: @lucsbelt None of these alternatives works with Quarkus. See the addition to my question.

Comment: This is a missing feature. Can you please open a ticket so we can address it?

Comment: @geoand do you have the link to the ticked?

Comment: I don't know if a ticket was ever opened for this

Comment: @geoand I didn't open a ticket.

Answer (score 8):

it is possible, your entity must extend PanacheEntityBase and use class level annotation @Table,@Entity,@IdClass(PK.class), where Pk is a POJO with fields of the composite primary key, then you have to declare the same fields with @Id annotation in your entity. eg:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "agent")
@IdClass(AgentPK.class)
public class AgentBRA extends PanacheEntityBase {

   @Id
   public Integer idUsuario;
   @Id
   public Integer idAgent;
```

and AgentPk:

```
public class AgentPK implements Serializable{

   protected Integer idUsuario;

   protected Integer idAgent;
   // getters setters and hascode and equals methods
```

Comment: This could well be a solution for the Hibernate ORM Panache provider. However, the problem (at least in my case, which is similar to the OP's) is with the Quarkus Spring Data JPA extension.

Comment: Sure, the solution provided was for the first versions of quarkus where the hibernate extension was still experimental.  At that time it was more stable and well documented using panache

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a repository with a composite key, do not use the Id annotation

```
            @Getter
            @Setter
            @NoArgsConstructor
            @AllArgsConstructor
            @ToString
            @Entity
            @Table(schema = "dbo", name = "PERSON")
            public class Person  extends PanacheEntityBase {
                
                
                @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
                @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false)
                private Integer id;
                
                @EmbeddedId
                private PersonId personId;
             
                @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
                private String address;
                
                @Column(name = "EMAIL")
                private String email;
                
                @Column(name = "PHONE_NUMBER")
                private String phoneNumber;
                
                
                @Getter
                @Setter
                @NoArgsConstructor
                @AllArgsConstructor
                @ToString
                @Embeddable
                public static class PersonId implements Serializable {

                    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
                    private String firstName;

                    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
                    private String lastName;

                    @Column(name = "DATE_OF_BIRTH")
                    private String dateOfBirth;

                }
            }
```

Repository

```
            public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Person.PersonId> {
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

For Quarkus Spring Data JPA, the solution is to switch from using @IdClass to @Embeddable, which is supported by the extension, contrary to OP's comment that "Quarkus currently doesn't allow other annotations than @Id" (that is if OP is using this extension, rather than Panache, which is not quite clear).

Simply annotate the primary key class with "@Embeddable":

```
@Embeddable
public class FooPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "fooId")
    private String fooId;

    @Column(name = "barId")
    private String barId;
    ...
```

Then use "@EmbeddedId" in the entity class (replacing the traditional multiple @Id definitions used with @IdClass method):

```
public class Foo implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    protected FooPK id;
    ...
```